# How to convert values in the string to hex in Hive

Tags: arrays, string, hive, hex, hiveql

I want to convert a string into hex, for example: there is a string as `'[1,2,3,4,5]'`, I want to convert this to hex and the output should be in string as follow: `'[31,32,33,35,35]'` using hiveQL

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading and trailing square brackets, split to array, explode, convert to HEX, then collect array again and finally concatenate it:

```
with data as (
select '[1,2,3,4,5]' str
)

select '['||concat_ws(',',collect_list(hex(e.a)))||']' as result
  from data d 
       lateral view explode(split(regexp_replace(str,'\\[|\\]',''),',')) e as a
```

result

```
[31,32,33,34,35]
```